# Possible to use arbitrary online webcam for skype video?

Tags: video, skype, webcam

Is there an (easy-ish) way to configure skype to use an external video feed as its "camera"?

I am generally opposed to showing my face during online meetings, preferring that the whiteboard be the focus of attention.

I would like to (instead) have my default video be of a publicly available video feed. I am eyeing up traffic cams in the area, possibly a parrot.

Example feed: https://www.novascotiawebcams.com/en/webcams/merlin-the-talking-parrot/

What I'm thinking is making the remote feed a local device on my computer. Not sure if that is a reasonable approach (or how to do that).